# Caputre Info and Extract it to text file

Tags: php, database, vb.net, ms-access

We have an existing Software that we don't have any source code of.

This software is somehow a Meeting Room Reservation System for a meeting Room with Time In and Time Out with Day Specified.

I was tasked to create a website for the reservation system but I dont have the means to read its database. It was built for a local PC that use ( .accdb, .db ) as its file system.

I cannot read the accdb because it is password protected.

I have three questions here.

First) Can I somehow capture the Text in the screen of the reservation system with any programming language.

Second) If not possible on the first, can I somehow crack the password of that accdb file so I can connect to it and get the information I need. or Crack Hex something of the Executable

Third) The System has moving numbers. For Ex: VisayasRoom: TimeIn: 2:35 Duration: 1minute 45seconds

can I somehow snipp that part with some software?

I cannot recreate our System as of the moment, as much as I want to. I hope my post does't get closed. I dont know where I could ask. I tried googling first and resulted here.

EDIT:
UPDATE
My database is a Standard Jet DB. when I tried to open it as notepad. this was in first line

Comment: What do you use to access the reservation system? A webpage? A local `.exe` client? What version of MS Access is it? Also, what information do you need out of the database?

Comment: Executable Only. It has Exe and accdb and db file in it. I dont know what version but I am guessing its 2000/2004 since it has been created around 2003 / 2004. And I also tried access password recovery demo. All Failed in other version except 2000 and told me I should buy Full version :(... I need the information on who reserved who for what day and time that is show on The Exe and display it in my PHP webpage.

Comment: If the db file is dBase, which uses the .db extension, you can read the data with a Microsoft driver (eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705/how-to-read-write-dbase-iii-files-using-c-net-odbc-or-ole/75915#75915) I think dBase runs to version V at this stage.

Comment: eventhough I dont have a password?

Answer (score 1):

If the `.db` file was created using  Microsoft Access 95/97/2000/XP or with the Jet Database Engine 3.0/4.0, "Access PassView" (free utility) should reveal the password. The site to download it is here: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try a screen scrapping utility like [SysExporter](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=32887.msg307110;topicseen)

But for unencrypting the database you will have to either use a specialist service or pay for a software to do it for you.
You could also try to hack the application that uses the database, but this may be quite complex and the password may be well hidden within its code.

Note that `.accdb` are newer Access database files, the new format was introduced in version 2007.
One more thing: the `.db` extension could refer to a Paradox database, or another format, and it will probably not open from Access, you'll have to find exactly what sort of database it is.

Comment: It might be that the previous programmer rename the database ext to accdb. The true file is .db extension. any ideas?

Comment: If I use sysexporter. How do I automate it and run it on background while my program does the rest. and how do I export it automatically lets say every minute.